# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Input::load_query()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been try learning codeigniter to build a simple web application. I got to make it work on my windows machine. However, when i migrated to a linux machine, im getting error. The one I'm stuck at now is: Fatal error: Call to undefined method `CI_Input::load_query()`. I found out that new php version doesn't support this function anymore. Can anybody tell me how should i change the following line in order to make it work?

The error im getting is at this line `$CI =& get_instance();`. Thank you in advance.

```
    function load_query($query_id) {

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $rows = $CI->db->get_where('ci_query', array('id' => $query_id))->result();
        if (isset($rows[0])) {
            parse_str($rows[0]->query_string, $_GET);
        }
    }
}
```